# Keep UNNotificationContent some seconds

Tags: ios, swift, call, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I'm doing an app in Swift 3 for iOS 10. I have done an UNNotificationContent to simulate a call in my app but it disappears approximately five seconds after being launched. I need to keep it more seconds, while the "calling" is in process. I want to keep the local notification until I call the removeAllPendingNotificationRequests method. Can I do it?

This is my code now:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.body = "\(userName) is calling..."
content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "sound_call.wav")
content.badge = 1

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: content, trigger: nil)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to control how long the notification stays on the screen. That's controlled by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.body = "\(userName) is calling..."
content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "sound_call.wav")
content.badge = 1

// choose a random identifier
let id = UUID().uuidString
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id, content: content, trigger: trigger)

// add our notification request
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
print("Notified!", title)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [id])
    print("Notification removed!", id)
}
```

Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68773924/46443

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP wants the displayed notification to stay longer than it normally does. Your posted answer simply tries to delete the requested notification 3 seconds after scheduling it. The trigger is likely much further in the future and not yet delivered when you try to delete it.