# Show Local push notification unless user taps on it

Tags: ios, swift

Here is how I create local notification which successfully shows after 3 seconds

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Test"
    content.body = "Test"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "UYLReminderCategory"
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3,
                                                    repeats: false)
    let identifier = "UYLLocalNotification"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "Snooze",
                                            title: "Snooze", options: [])
    let deleteAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "UYLDeleteAction",
                                            title: "Delete", options: [.destructive])
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "UYLReminderCategory",
                                          actions: [snoozeAction,deleteAction],
                                          intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    center.setNotificationCategories([category])

    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Something went wrong
        }
    })
```

but its hides after few seconds, is it possible to prevent it from hiding, like in apples build in Alarm app.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346256/keep-unnotificationcontent-some-seconds If there is no property specific on the UserNotification.framework, you shouldn't be able to do so. Also, there is an options in Settings.app/Notifications/ Show Temporary/Persistent. But you can't bypass the user setting.

Comment: does that mean that Apple's alarm app uses some private api, because its shows banner really longer than in other other apps?

Comment: Yes, I think so, because it doesn't even appear on the Settings.app/Notifications list of apps. You can't change anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification's behavior is controlled by the system and **your app can not override it.**
The user [is in control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201925) of how your app's notifications should display.

[image: Image from Apple's user support page]
*Image from Apple's user support [page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201925)*

Comment: does that mean that Apple's alarm app uses some private api, because its shows banner really longer than in other other apps?

Comment: Absolutely. Apple do whatever they please with their system 

Comment: ok thanks, and last question, is it possible to bring app from background to foreground when getting push notification?

Comment: You can’t force your app to open without the user deciding to manually do so (them taping the notification).