# Is it possible to delete a notification seconds after sending it in Swift 5.4?

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to write a function that sends a notification that contains private user data that can be automatically deleted after 5 seconds using the following code:

```
Button("Send Notification that self deletes after 5 seconds") {
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Notification Title"
                content.body = "Body"
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                
                let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
                
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10, execute: {
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
                })
```

However, the notification still remains on the notification centre and lock screen. I can only manage to have `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()` work by opening the app. I have googled solutions for this answer for hours and can't seem to find one. Would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store notification `id`

```
let id = UUID().uuidString
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id, content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

And then you'll be able to remove it using `removeDeliveredNotifications`:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [id])
```

Comment: I tried and it still doesn’t work. I don’t think that the id is the issue here. The `removeDeliveredNotifications` only triggers if i launch the app again.

Comment: @cfyjdfk is `removeDeliveredNotifications` called when app is in foreground?

Comment: I don’t think I am able to test that as I can only receive notifications from the app when it is in the background. As soon as i receive the notification and run the app in the foreground,  `removeDeliveredNotifications` runs.

Comment: @cfyjdfk If your app is in background, you can try using a background job to do it. But this won't work if you app was closed or dismissed long ago. The only really stable way of doing so is using server notifications

Comment: Hi Phillip, sorry to disturb you but I'm not exactly sure how to run the background job you mentioned even after googling it as most of the solutions pertain to UIKit. Would you able to assist me? Thanks in advance

Comment: @cfyjdfk check out on [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler), I'm afraid I haven't worked with this personally so I can't assist you